# Arcpy Cell Statistics - maximum number of input rasters

Tags: arcpy, spatial-analyst

I am running cell statistics in arcpy. Essentially I am summing together a folder of grd files to create a new grd representing their sum

This will eventually take place on a folder of 20,000 raster grds.

Is there a maximum number of raster datasets that can be processed by the cellStatistics tool?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The help for this [tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009z0000007q000000) does not explicitly state there is a limit but in a project about a year ago I was feeding it folders with many thousands of rasters and the performance was very poor. What I eventually did was SUM the rasters in batches of 100 then SUMMED the batched values. This ran much quicker and was easily implemented with a bit of looping in Python and ArcPy.

Comment: Good to know. I will probably do something like this once I get my 20k ready for summing together

Comment: +1 For many reasons, sticking thousands of files in one folder is rarely a good idea.  A better organization would have the files arranged into a hierarchy of folders, each containing far fewer datasets.  That would practically force one to implement this (better) solution in the first place.